# checking if a directory exists in any drive of a client machine using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, file-io, filesystems

a user has a directory in C drive of his computer and another user has directory in E drive.

```
user A:E:\SoonrWorkplace\Clients
user B: E:\SoonrWorkplace\ABC\Clients
```

i have to check if the directory exists by tripping drive name from the path i.e \SoonrWorkplace\ABC\Clients

here is the code

```
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClientRootFolder.Text))
            {
                string Filepath = txtClientRootFolder.Text.Trim();

                if (Directory.Exists(Filepath))
                {
                    checkClientRootFolder.Visible = true;
                    imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/Images/tick.png";
                }
                else
                {
                    checkClientRootFolder.Visible = true;
                    imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/Images/remove.png";
                }


            }

where Filepath="\SoonrWorkplace\ABC\Clients"
```

Comment: You cannot check a folder on the client computer from a website.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out [Directory.Exsists()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  if(Directory.Exists("Your file path")) 
   {
     //Do something 
   }
```

Comment: if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtClientRootFolder.Text))
        {
            string Filepath = txtClientRootFolder.Text.Trim();

            if (Directory.Exists(Filepath))
            {
                checkClientRootFolder.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/Images/tick.png";
            }
            else
            {
                checkClientRootFolder.Visible = true;
                imgstatus.ImageUrl = "~/Images/remove.png";
            }


        }

Comment: I should have been more clear. Please edit your question to include your code, comments are not for code.

Comment: And what is the result of this code? Does it detect your directory? If your file path is correct and it exists it will return true.

Comment: its returning false for some cases as user will not enter the full path.

Comment: Well then, how do you expect to check if a directory exists without knowing its location?

Comment: is there a way to check all the drives?

Comment: If you know where abouts the folder you're searching for is you could use GetDirectories method which would return a list of directories as strings and then you iterate it using the Exists method.